# Error while i am clicking on user full details page (Angular 14)

Tags: angular

main.ts:6 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at ContactUserDetailsComponent_Template (contact-user-details.component.html:17:25)
at executeTemplate (core.mjs:10534:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:10419:13)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:11480:13)
at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:10210:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:10469:13)
at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:11434:17)
at refreshView (core.mjs:10443:9)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:11480:13)
at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:10210:9)

Answer (score 0):

Check The content of "contact-user-details.component.html", there is a object variable (maybe "User" object) which is using in the template of component.
its Null or undefined in the current component lifecycle.